# Firebase .on('value') not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im following this video right [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX).

And here's my codes.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fire Test</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Value -->
        <pre id="object"></pre>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCOJZqfas4gxwEYBbRNyyIy7Z9vEsTx4ME",
        authDomain: "fire-test-e2185.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://fire-test-e2185.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "fire-test-e2185.appspot.com",
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var preObject = document.getElementById('object');


    // Create reference 
    var dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object')

    console.log('test log'); // logging

    // Sync object changes
    dbRefObject.on('value', function (snap) {
        console.log(snap.val()); // not logging
    });

    console.log('test log'); // logging
})();
```

**Output**

[image]

**BTW**

Here's the structure of my test project in case maybe it matters.

```
fire-test
    |_ index.html
    |_ app.js
```

And im running it on `apache` under `/var/www/html/fire-test`

`http://localhost/fire-test/`

Comment: without those basic rules in place.  if you accidentally say db.ref().set('') you erase your entire db

Comment: @RonRoyston Ooh. I see, thanks!. Anyways, so If the basic rules is set to 'not public' how do i authenticate the request?

Comment: You can't if read and write are set to `true` at the root.  The default rules are setup so that only authenticated users have write access.  You can make the rules very granular is you want to.

Comment: @RonRoyston I see. But how do you actually 'authenticate' the user.

Comment: Use the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) system.  This might give you a head start - https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually firebase's database has it's authentication and I found out that the rules on my database is not set properly (to public).

I changed this :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

`"auth != null"` to `true`

**Note**

Setting the **rules** this way is a bad idea. We don't want anyone to access the `root` node. Though in this answer, this is just to test out the firebase connection.

Comment: brilliant! Saved me from scratching my hair out.

Comment: Why it doesn't return an explicit error (Eg: 403 user do not have the permission)? Working with firebase relating to error handling is really a pain

Comment: mine had read/write set to expire at a certain time (~1 week after creating it?). would have been nice to know this prior to spending 15 minutes feverishly parsing my code and discovering onValue never fired (and is in fact an event listener abstracted into a function in firebase 10...)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just get a returned object containing the current values stored at that location in your `firebase` db, change `.on` to `.once`.

Using `.on` indicates that you want something to dynamically happen every time the argued event occurs, but `.once` indicates that you just was the current data at that location.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I figured out the problem. See my answer.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx oh ok good! Forgot it could be an `auth` issue too. Glad its fixed.

Comment: I think the order of their tutorials should be the `auth` first lol. :D

Thanks again.

Comment: Are .on and .once specific to Firebase, Javascript or JQuery? It is such a common word - tracking down its origin seems to be challenging. Also - is the term for what "ON" is a "promise"?

Comment: @Praxiteles Here's a link to the Firebase documentation that explains the child event listeners - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events Basically you can listen to dynamic changes to your data, for example - if you have the .on "child_added" listener on a ref then each time a child is added to the ref you've specified, the data at that node gets fetched. Hope this helps.